# node.js JSON Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I get this error massage

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)

after I used res.json on my code

```
app.post('/dispalymove', function (req, res, next) {

var lMove="";


if(req.body.MoveString !== null){
     Move.setMoveUserId(req.user.id);
     Move.setMoveString(req.body.MoveString);
     a.getLastMove(req.user.GameId,function(move){
      console.log("Return from display move:",move)
        res.json({"msg": move, "loggedin": "true"});


      });


    } else {

              var output = {"msg": lMove, "loggedin": "true"}
               res.json(output);
    }

});
```

the function that I called in another file move.js

```
getLastMove(id,callback){


    var MoveRequest = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";

    var query = connection.query(MoveRequest, function(err,rows, result) {

    if (rows.length == 0) { 
        return "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
    }
    if (rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i in rows) {

            var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
            if (rows[i].GameId == id){

                callback(move);
            }

        }
    }


    });


        var move="rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
        return move;


}
```

**UPDATE**
I tried but a return after res,json like the example in the duplicated link and tried to comment the other app.post where i callback move but i still get this error i get the output in the first time the page load then server give me this error so that's not mean the request being left "dangling" so what's the wrong ?

the other app.post where I call "move" to

```
app.post('/insertmove', function (req, res, next) {

var lMove="rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";


if(req.body.MoveString !== null){
     Move.setMoveUserId(req.user.id) ;
     Move.setMoveString(req.body.MoveString);
     a.InsertMove(req.user.GameId);
     a.getLastMove(req.user.GameId,function(move){
     console.log("Return from insertmove move:",move)
           var output = {"msg": move, "loggedin": "true"}; 

           return res.send(JSON.stringify(output));

      });


    } else {


             var output = {"msg": lMove, "loggedin": "true"}; // <=== here lCol always equals ""

             return res.send(JSON.stringify(output));

    }


});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: This isn't a complete example; you'll get dinged on that.  Basically, res.json may set headers so you need to be sure that nothing prior to this sends any data to the response object.  It would appear that getLastMove could call the callback more than once; the 2nd time it calls it it would trigger this kind of error.

Comment: @Joe i have another app.post function that callback getLastMove are that the problem ?

Comment: Also: your `return move;` at the end of `getLastMove` isn't going to do anything.  You're not using the return value in your calling code, you're expecting the callback to get handed that info.  I'd expect that return to instead be `callback(move);`

Comment: For any given request, you can only send one response.  You should make sure `getLastMove` does what you think it does, especially in that loop.  You're assuming I think that it only finds one matching row.

Comment: There are also cases when getLastMove will not call the callback at all, which will lead to the request being left "dangling"

Comment: I tried but a return after res,json like the example in the duplicated link and tried to comment the other app.post where i callback move but i still get this error i get the output in the first time the page load then server give me this error so that's not mean the request being left "dangling" so what's the wrong ?

Comment: @jcaron i updated my post can you check that please

Comment: @Joe i tried to remove the other app.post where i call it again but did't work and check my new post update i added the other app.post code

Comment: As pointed out, the issue is in your getLastMove function. You need to make sure it always calls the callback once, never more, never less. Currently it can call it 0, 1 or more times. Whenever it doesn't call it or calls it several times you'll have an issue.

Comment: You can only send a response once. If you send it more than once you will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by adding return after callback

```
    var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
    if (rows[i].GameId == id){

        callback(move);
    }
```

like that

```
    var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
    if (rows[i].GameId == id){

        callback(move);
        return;
    }
```